# Wix 3.5 preprocessor extension - undefined preprocessor function

Tags: wix, preprocessor, wix3.5

I just using Wix 3.5 with Visual Studio 2010, Windows 7. I unable to make a custom `Preprocessor Extension` run. I create the **extension project** in .NET 3.5. and copy the compiled dll into **Wix 3.5 program files**, plus set the **Reference Path** in the extension project properties but the **Wix project** build still failed with "**undefined preprocessor function**" on my extension.

Example:
Extension project: WixFileVersionExtension (from wixfileversionext.codeplex.com)
Wix program files: "C:\Program Files\Windows Installer XML v3.5\bin"

Am I missing something? Google can't answer me.

---

**Update:**
This is a bug and has been reported here http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&atid=642714&aid=3212304&group_id=105970

---

**Update:**
Do not use **Reference Path** in the VS project property as stated here http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/votive_property_pages.htm *The Reference Paths section allows you to define paths you want to use when locating references (WiX extensions and WiX libraries)*

or copy the extension dll into Wix folder as stated here http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/extension_development_intro.htm *Placed next to WiX EXEs along with all other WiX extension DLLs*

The **Solution** is: **Add Reference** and **Browse** the extension **dll file** INSTEAD OF Add Reference by **Project** even if you have those projects in one solution. If you want to follow the Configuration, **Debug** or **Release**, unload the Wix project, edit the .wixproj file and change the `..\WixExtension\bin\Debug\WixExtension.dll` to `..\WixExtension\bin\$(Configuration)\WixExtension.dll` so it will become like this:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <WixExtension Include="WixExtension">
      <HintPath>..\WixExtension\bin\$(Configuration)\WixExtension.dll</HintPath>
      <Name>WixExtension</Name>
    </WixExtension>
  </ItemGroup>
```

**Note:** Wix Visual Studio project will only assume it is Wix Extension whenever you **Add Reference** by **dll** file (Browse) and also only assume it is an application to be included in the **installer** whenever you **Add Reference** by **Project**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the actual extension assembly (.dll) so that Candle.exe loads it. The command-line equivalent is -ext.

Comment: I see...First I try to add reference but not work. Then I realize I need to copy the dll into the wix folder, but I remove the reference. Let me try both add reference and put the dll in the wix folder tomorrow. I am using Visual Studio Wix Project, not MSBuild from command line, does it related to the Candle.exe?

Comment: Candle.exe is the WiX compiler. Extensions don't have to be in the WiX binaries directory; you can add the reference in the .wixproj in Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes last time I set the **Reference Path** in the VS project and in Wix folder to double check but didn't not work. Now I try both add reference and set path (+ copy to wix folder) but also not working. It still not recongnize the custom prefix.
-------------------
Wait, I see there is no -ext and the **Reference Path** i set in the VS does not included in the Build output. Seems bug in the Wix Votive release in Wix 3.5. I want to send bug report in SourceForge but they moved to CodePlex.

Comment: Yes, add reference but use `Browse` to specify the dll file directly.