# Visual Studio doesn't release files used in WiX Extension

Tags: wix, wix-extension

I have a problem with building wixproj under Visual Studio.

What I have done:

- added my preprocessor extension as separate project (wile reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296179/wix-3-5-preprocessor-extension-undefined-preprocessor-function) post)
- added my extension method invocation in Product.wxs file

First compilation works perfectly. I see changes made in Product.wxs. Things are going wrong while building second, third, fourth time and so on.

This is what I get:

> "Unable to copy file
>   "obj\x86\Release\WixStringFormattingExtension.dll" to
>   "bin\Release\WixStringFormattingExtension.dll". The process cannot
>   access the file 'bin\Release\WixStringFormattingExtension.dll' because
>   it is being used by another process."

Restarting Visual Studio helps ... but only for first compilation. It seems like something (light.exe candle.exe devenv.exe) is not releasing files.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug report instead of a question... That said to confirm your suspicion you could always use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to figure out what process is holding a handle to your files. To do that, run it, hit Ctrl+F, and type the name of your file: WixStringFormattingExtension.dll